# Is this patent just for the collar of the cane in 5 horizontal lines or for any crystals

Tags: claims

In reference to the patent: [USD679492](https://www.google.com/patents/USD679492)

Is this patent just for the collar of the cane in 5  horizontal lines or for any crystals applied to any cane in any design ?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a design patent, the patent covers the particular design shown in the figures and any design substantially similar enough that someone would be deceived into buying it believing they were getting the one described in the patent.

So it certainly covers 5 horizontal lines of crystals around the collar of a cane, but not necessarily any crystal applied to any cane in any design.  In order to get a better idea of what might be substantially similar, see [this answer](https://patents.stackexchange.com/a/11955/9802) to [How can I make sure my design doesn't infringe on existing design patents?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/q/11919/9802)

Note that in this case, the dotted lines mean that the handle is not claimed as part of the design. The two collars at the bottom are included, in addition to the crystals at the top.